# JPA criteriabuilder java date object issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When java date object is equal to, it is not returning any results, greater than and less than working fine, but not equal, what changes should i need to make?

The datatype in the database is Date and value is "13-JAN-14 05:00:00" and java model object datatype is java.util.Date, date value output "Mon Jan 13 05:00:00 PST 2014". i dont know why it is working for equal?

```
Constraint startDateConstraint = filter.getConstraint(MarketingOfferSearchFilter.Field.READY_DATE);
        if (startDateConstraint != null) {
            Expression<Date> startDate = marketingOffer.get(Offer_.startDate);
            Date stDate = DateUtil.convertDifferentDateStringToUTCDate((String) startDateConstraint.getValue());
            if (startDateConstraint.getCompareMode().equals(CompareMode.DATE_BEFORE)) {

                predicates.add(builder.lessThan(startDate, stDate));
            } else if (startDateConstraint.getCompareMode().equals(CompareMode.DATE_AFTER)) {
                predicates.add(builder.greaterThan(startDate, stDate));
            } else {
                predicates.add(builder.equal(startDate, stDate));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you are comparing a DATE with a DATETIME/TIMESTAMP with an extra HH:mm:sss?

Comment: Hi Joop, The datatype in the database is Date and value is "13-JAN-14 05:00:00" and  date comparing is "Mon Jan 13 05:00:00 PST 2014". any idea what i am missing?

Comment: Can you format your dates to database date format and try again  ?

Comment: did you find solution for this ?if there is a date format issue then why it works for lesser and greater than"s ?